# FX7400: LLRP error: "Report Buffer Overflow Error Event (251)"

Tags: rfid, motorola-emdk, llrp

I have few Motorola FX7400 readers that read RFID tags on production line + app based on EMDK(EMDK for .NET v2.8) to fetch inventory data. 
Randomly(?) some of readers stop to deliver correct tag inventory report and continously return "Report Buffer Overflow Error Event (251)".

What is the reason of such behaviour and how to solve this?

I am attaching Wireshark screenshot.

[image: Wireshark screenshot]

Comment: Did you have contact to motorola/zebra support? Do you have the latest firmware installed? Sounds like a problem for their support. Actually their support is quite OK.

Comment: @etalon11 just checking firmware - it is outdated indeed. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: You were successful?

Comment: @etalon11 - don't know yet, I sent firmware update request and we will see :)